# Error laravel 8 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, rest, axios

Hola tengo una API en laravel 8. Estoy intentando acceder a localhost:8000/test y recibo error "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException". Tengo el front en vue y accedo de axios.

Configuración axios en front 'utils/axios.js':

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/';
axios.defaults.timeout = 18000;

export default axios;
```

Index.vue (desde donde se hace la petición):

```
import axios from '../utils/axios';

export default {
  name: 'PageIndex',
  methods: {
    test() {
      axios.get('test')
        .then(() => {
          console.log('ok');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Archivo 'routes/api.php' de laravel:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');
```

He probado tanto `Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');` como `Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');` y sigue sin funcionar....

Ya no se que mas mirar.

Un saludo y gracias por las respuestas :)

Comment: En Laravel 8 esa ya no es la forma de invocar a los controladores y sus métodos

Comment: Y como se haría, estoy viendo la docu y no veo nada mal :(

Comment: Si ya encontraste la solución a tu pregunta, marca tu respuesta como aceptada (deberás esperar 48 horas) e incluye información adicional, en lugar de editar tu pregunta agregando "solución" o similares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema es que estaba llamando a localhost/test y tendría que llamar a localhost/api/test